# AT command for SIM Pin retries left

Tags: at-command, modem

Does anyone know an AT command that will allow me to query how many retries of entering PIN on a SIM card before it locks me out?

I've tried AT+CPIN? but that does not give me how many times I can enter the PIN before I need a PUK.
How do normal phones do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not part of the ETSI spec so it depends on the equipment your using.

It's most often called the "Pin Counter" and can be read via `AT^SPIC` however your best bet is looking for "Pin Counter" in the devices AT command documentation.

Comment: On telit platforms there is a command called AT#PCT which tells the remaining attempts.

Answer (score 5):

The latest 3GPP spec lists the command you want as `+CPINR`

Answer (score 2):

You could use a generic approach for >=3G, this should work independent of the modem manufacturer, as it directly communicates with the sim card (UICC).
It reads the PIN retry counter from the UICC

```
AT+CSIM=10,"0020000100"
```

The `AT+CSIM` command sends a (raw) command to the sim card.
The sim card responds a bit cryptic with one of:

- `+CSIM: 4,"63CX"` X is the hex-value of the remaining retries for
  pin1 (range 0-A=0-10 retries remaining)
- `+CSIM: 4,"6A88"` pin1 is not initialized/available
- `+CSIM: 4,"6983"` pin1
  is blocked.